# MatLab Regexprep Syntax with $ sign

Tags: matlab

Here is a line using `regexprep`.

```
line = regexprep(line,'(,([^0-9])',' , $1');
```

What does the `$1` syntax mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$1` in the [replacement string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html#inputarg_replace) provided to `regexprep` references the first matched token in your regular expression.

So for example, if we match two tokens, we can replace the matched string with either the first token

```
regexprep('abcdefgh', '(ab)(cd)', '$1')
% abefgh
```

Second token

```
regexprep('abcdefgh', '(ab)(cd)', '$2')
%   cdefgh
```

Or both tokens

```
regexprep('abcdefgh', '(ab)(cd)', '$1$2')
%   abcdefgh
```

In your example, the part matched by`([^0-9])` is the token referenced by `$1`. The code that you have posted, removes the `(,` from a string and replaces it with `,` and the `$1` keeps the rest of the match the same.

```
line = 'abcd(,abcd';
regexprep(line,'(,([^0-9])',' , $1')
%   abcd , abcd
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!